# Isekai manga with a saintess who is going to die soon

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Does anyone know the name of an isekai that has a girl who is a priestess and is going to die since the church is secretly against her. She ends up meeting the mage of the magic tower (he is in a disguise) and they become friends. She even does a talent show with his help and learns how to use her saintess powers. The mage hides his eyes (not sure why since I didn't get far) and his disguise is him with dark brown hair that covers his eyes while his real appearance is him with long white hair with a ribbon that covers his eyes. I read this about may or so but I don't know if they changed the cover but I can not find it in my reading list

Edit: THANK YOU FOR HELPING, the webtoon was found

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How long ago did you read this?  ("A while back" isn't very specific.)

Comment: If you read this on mangago, I presume you're trying to find it so that you can purchase it legally and support the author.

Comment: Presumably, but providing the source website may help with the search.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white, and what colour was the saintess' hair?

Comment: @DavidW it was about this year, in May or so

Comment: @LogicDictates it was in color, I believe the saintess had blonde hair?

Comment: @valorum yes, I'm trying to find it so I can read the rest and see who the author is so I can support them

Comment: Thanks to everyone who is helping out btw :) I appreciate it

Comment: Just to confirm, is this definitely an isekai, i.e. did it involve someone being transported to another world? Also, how was the priestess going to die? Was she going to be executed/murdered? Was she ill or cursed? Something else?

Comment: Do you know how she's aware the church is against her and that she's going to die? Is this an isekai into a novel/game so she knows the plot? Or does she go back in time after being killed once? Or are they just standard jerks? For the ribbon, is it covering his eyes like a blindfold, or just a facial decoration? Do you remember how many chapters you read?

Comment: @LogicDictates yes, she was gonna die by the magician in the tower I'm not sure how tho

Comment: @qazmlpok yes she is aware of the church and that's she's gonna die. She knows the plot I'm pretty sure it's a game where she played on hard mode and always kept on dying by the magician (I can't remember the details). The ribbon hides his eyes like a blindfold and are used for hiding his identity and for safety of other people. Not sure how many chapters I read probably around 10 or 15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi there I think the manhwa your talking about is *[How To Clear A Dating Sim As A Side Character](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/how-to-clear-a-dating-sim-as-a-side-character)*. That's the only manhwa I know that fits your description.

[image: Cover image of How To Clear A Dating Sim As A Side Character]

> When Yewon opens her eyes inside Midnight, the top-ranked dating simulation game, she realizes things aren’t quite as fun when her own life is at stake without a “Load Save” option. The only way to clear Midnight is to reach a happy ending with one of the five love interests, but each route poses a different set of problems. Meeting the master of the mage’s tower will lead to almost certain death, the crown prince doesn’t even try to hide his animosity towards her, the merchant seems to be missing a few screws, and another barely speaks. The swordmaster seems relatively normal, but it turns out he’s a devout follower of the temple she’s desperately trying to escape. Will Yewon be able to capture the heart of one of these men and use her insider game knowledge to clear the game?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you [edit] your answer to include a summary of this, or at least a link to a summary?  Don't force everyone to look it up to see if your answer is good, provide some information _here_ they can look at.

Comment: The initial panels has the saintess being murdered by a member of the church before Yewon wakes up in her body, but I don't currently have access to the sites that serialize this, so I can't share the image.